# Mappend missing in Haskell instance

Tags: haskell

I am compiling a Haskell project and get a message I have not seen before. Does anyone know what exactly is missing?

```
No instance nor default method for class operation mappend
```

The corresponding code is:

```
instance S.Semigroup Macros where 
    x <> y = Macros
        (commands x ++ commands y)
        (environments x ++ environments y)
        (counters x ++ counters y)
```

The function `mappend` seems to be an associate operator but I am not familiar yet with Haskell.

Comment: That's not the corresponding code. `mappend` comes from the `Monoid` typeclass, so the corresponding code should include it, rather than just `Semigroup`.

Comment: Are you sure that's the code responsible? That error message seems much more likely to be associated with an empty `Monoid` instance later in the code.

Comment: Agree! I found the solution. `mappend` needs to be added.

Comment: @DanielStephens: normally `mappend` uses as default `(<>)`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#Monoid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning comes from the definition of a `Monoid` instance, probably somewhere later in the code, which you left (half) empty.

You probably have something like

```hs
instance Monoid Macros where
    mempty = Macros [] [] []
```

However, since `mappend` is a member of `Monoid`, you should write

```
instance Monoid Macros where
    mempty = Macros [] [] []
    mappend = (<>)
```

Note: since base-4.11 (GHC-8.2) the `mappend` can be omitted, as there is default definition in the type-class

```hs
class Semigroup => Monoid m where
    -- | Identity of 'mappend'
    mempty  :: a

    -- | An associative operation
    --
    -- __NOTE__: This method is redundant and has the default
    -- implementation @'mappend' = '(<>)'@ since /base-4.11.0.0/.
    mappend :: a -> a -> a
    mappend = (<>)
```

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#mappend

Leaving `mappend = (<>)` in the instance is fine, if you need to support multiple GHC versions.